# Where should I put the bridge of a warship?

Tags: science-fiction, spaceships

I am currently designing spaceship for my world. I want to use good ol' physics, so no handwavium here.

I assume that my crew will remain in weightlessness during maneuvers. Since there is no up and down, or right and left, there is no direction that is more privileged than others, espacially during combat.

**Where should I put the bridge of a spaceship ?** (in term of arrangement and placement)

---

### Details

---

In the Expanse for instance, the bridge level is perpendicular to the ship's central axis, to generate artificial gravity when thrusting forward.

My main source of inspiration is the design of Alliance's ships in the anime "Legends of the galactic heroes: die neue These". Here are some examples :

[image: An example]

[image: A second example]

On this design, the bridge is retracted inside the ship during fights.

### Overall design choices

Ships will be equiped with fixed weaponry (Railguns) mounted along their axis. They will be non-symetrical with main propulsion systems installed near the prow (like the pictures above) installed. I will follow the same design guidelines as the ships presented above.

### Role of the bridge

[image: Bridge]

The bridge is where information from all main functions of the ship should be summarized. It is where the captain and officers are, and where the steering, and tactical decisions are taken. The details of the decisions, are handled by crew members on other decks. Like in Space Battleship Yamato 2199, see picture above.

Comment: I would NOT put it on top-center or in the nose if I could help it. Too exposed to enemy fire. Unless you need actual windows.

Comment: What's your ship like? The idea that up/down/right/left is not meaningful isn't really true. To picture it, if all your cannons are on the "right" ⏩  side of the ship, then you want the "right" ⏩ to be always facing towards the enemy ⏩⚓⚠️. Therefore it gives a direction relative to said enemy :). Only symmetrical ships are not subject to that, but it's inefficient to spread firepower and defense all around you ⏩⏪⏫⏬.

Comment: Besides I see you used the hard-science tag. However, such tag means that answers need to use scientifically approved papers, yet you don't really provide enough details about your ships or weapons to be able to make use of such element. Not sure you have scientific documentation on futuristic space warfare either. Did you perhaps wanted to use the [tag:science-based] or [tag:science-fiction] tags? They're restraining less the answers.

Comment: "*In the Expanse for instance, the bridge level is perpendicular to the ship's central axis, to generate artificial gravity when thrusting forward.*" I do not see why the entire ship wouldn't be like that.

Comment: @Tortliena I will update the tags with science-fiction. There are indeed no scientific papers about that topic

Comment: @Tortliena as for the spaceship overall design, my main source of inspiration is the anime "Legends of the galactic heroes: die neue These", especially spaceships of the Alliance navy. I will add images in the post

Comment: How *big* of a ship? The classical sci-fi "bridge" encompasses a number of functions that, in a bigger ship like a modern aircraft carrier, can and do get split out into their own rooms. If you do that, what makes sense for one may not make sense for another.

Comment: As you go about making up ship designs for you world you're going to have to decide on what your design criteria are and what does and does not matter. For instance you seem to be prioritizing non-orientability, which greatly influences your design, there are many other design choices and trade-offs anyone will need to make during a design. Since you haven't specified your design priorities, this question is going to hinge too much on the opinions of individual answerers to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Cadence This is a command bridge, mostly to direct operations. A good example of what I am trying to do is something along the lines of the bridge of the Yamato (from the anime (again!) Space Battleship Yamato 2199). Main functions of the ships are directed by officers from the bridge, while the details are handled on lower bridges by other people.

Comment: Those pictures of ships seem to have clearly defined facings, the front, back, top. bottom, and sides are all distinct and one would assume that there is a preferable orientation of the ship relative to targets, or enemy fire.

Comment: @sphennings indeed, in this design, gun are mounted on the frontal side of the spaceship and they are fixed. It is very hard to escape from this, because we live in a space, where directions are correctly defined. I will refine the post with more details.

Comment: Given that the ships are orientable there will be a preferred orientation, probably not relative to gravity, but relative to objects in space.

Comment: Indeed, or you make spheres, with weapons everywhere, but this is not very interesting.

Comment: It depends on the way your world works. The visual style of Star Wars is of WWI/II combat at relatively close ranges where visually identifying what is happening to the ship and its surroundings are important (ignoring the written lore which is all over the place and makes no sense, fighter craft would barely notice the Death Star at the speed they are supposed to be going). While Star Trek is a more submarine experience where all data is basically fed through sensors and we only see representations of what happens on screen. Both have different command deck requirements.

Comment: VTC as too subjective. It's too dependent on the specific design of the ship, it's maneuvering capabilities, it's armaments and defenses, the materials science behind its construction, where everything else inside the ship is (like where all the water is... physics, right? Can't magically ignore it). To add insult to injury, you need to justify things like windows if we're going to apply physics (windows = bad). So, missing tons of details.

Comment: Also, please (please, please) read the tag wikis. You *cannot* use [tag:hard-science], [tag:science-based], [tag:science-fiction], or [tag:internal-consistency] together. Those wikis are important (especially for those four tags).

Comment: *Why bridges are located where they are* is **so that they can *see***. If the Apollo command module didn't have a window they would have died. The bridge of an aircraft carrier is seven stories above the deck. The bridge of a submarine is beneath wherever the periscope is. Take away the 'window' and it doesn't matter, until there's a system wide failure and you can't navigate. *"Is the sun coming up?" -"Yes, sir." -"Then put it on the left."*

Comment: @JBH thanks, I will carefully read the description before using these tags next time.

Answer (score 6):

The question to answer is "*what is the bridge for*?"

- Is it where the pilot sits, to steer the spacecraft? does the spacecraft even *need* a meatbag steer? If they do, why can't they just plug in a joystick and a VR headset in anywhere?
- Is it where the captain sits, to give orders to their subordinate meatbags? Do they need to be anywhere in particular?
- Is it where the strategic or tactical staff sit, in order to make combat decisions?
- If you're replicating WW1/WW2 air combat, is it where flights are directed from?
- Does the senior office present need to address important groups of people in person? Is it some kind of briefing room on top of all the rest?

They don't all need to be the same place. Wet navy ships (at least, the surface kind) and aircraft (at least the non-remote-piloted kind) need to put the person doing the steering somewhere they can look where they're going. Windows are a dangerous vulnerability on *any* kind of spacecraft, a place where micrometeors and radiation can waft in uninvited through awkward-to-shield transparent bits.

Consider following the [Combat Information Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_information_center) idea, something which started life in science fiction before escaping into real world military architecture. It should be as deep in the ship as is practical, so (ideally) it will be the bit that can survive the most damage and still co-ordinate activities on and around the spacecraft. You say it should be aligned to the thrust axis of the ship, but really *all* portions of the spacecraft where people are expected to work should be laid out that way.

Comment: i have refined my question. My main source of inspiration here is the command center from Space Battleship Yamato 2199. I will check the link you provided.

Comment: a CIC is indeed what i am looking for, and this is, to some extent, the purpose of the bridge of the Yamato.

Comment: "need to put the person doing the steering somewhere they can look where they're going." +1. "Windows are a dangerous vulnerability" -1.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue for centrally located to the greatest extent possible (possibly along with quarters for high-ranking crew). The bridge contains personnel that are vital for the continued operation as a warship and thus should be placed in a location with the most protection practical.

Take guidance from submarines but also note that space-warships have a slightly more advantageous position that while damage to the pressure hull is dangerous to whatever is nearby, a well designed warship should be able to seal off damage and only lose part of its function (I suppose certain parts may make damage a total write-off, engines for example). A submarine, on the other hand, due to the inward nature of the pressure experienced will likely be a total write-off upon any puncture of the pressure hull.

Comment: This answer reminds me of Futurama: "*Dear Lord, that's over 150 atmospheres of pressure.*"

"**How many atmospheres can this ship withstand?**"

"Well it's a spaceship, so I'd say anywhere between zero and one.*"

Comment: Made me think of the Borg sphere at the centre of the cube in First Contact.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there would be two main ways to place a command bridge on a ship.

1: WWI/II combat.

You have combat mostly in visual range of one another. You want to be able to see what is happening to your ship, the fighters leaving the ship (if any) and visually spot what your opponents are doing.

For this the citadel type of command structure is great. You have a regular outer command area where you can look out of the windows and see what is going on. However in combat most of the really important people move into the citadel, basically an extra armored bunker inside the somewhat armored outer command area where the command staff has less situational awareness but a hit on the outer bridge is less likely to kill the entire command staff.

2: "Submarine" warfare like Star trek.

All fights happen at such long ranges only sensors can be relied upon to detect and fire on anything. My pet peeve with Star Trek is that bridges tend to be placed as exposed as possible, without the need for it. Especially considering how often they can just target the weapons and stop a ship its ludicrous to place a bridge so exposed.

Smart design in this situation would be to have a bridge as deep inside as you can, away from other essential systems to limit potential secondary damage, surrounded by more armor.

Additional protections would be to not place it in the exact same position each time to prevent enemies from more easily targeting you. Since you'll be using output from computers to control the ship you can also disperse the command center and have different rooms, all connected with screens and/or holograms to talk to one another. No one is going to kill or capture the entire command crew easily if they all are in different locations. On top of that you can have each location dedicated, letting each top of their branch (say the tactical officer) communicate with several people under him directly in his room without disturbing all the chatter going on in the "bridge" communication channels. This decreases response time as the chief officer can delegate commands to others quickly and also receive information relevant to them more easily and then relay what they need to the other chief/command staff.

Answer (score 0):

#### Current placement

Casual navigation of youtube has recent video about why bridges are where they are on contemporary ships. Essentially trade offs between lines of sight, proximity of other resources(engine room, crew quarters), safety(away from bow, close to safety equipment), ease of navigation(where is center of rotation).

#### Place to maximize utility.

Any reasonable space based warship will have

- lots of automation
- fly by wire
- instrument based visualization and location systems

There is no need to base the helm close to a non-existent rudder with a observation platform/bridge near enough for a captain to shout orders to. Therefor the bridge may be placed anywhere. Closer to the more interior protected areas of the ship seem most reasonable. Both to maximize protection of the command crew and to minimize rotation forces. That is, whatever maximizes ability for command crew to command, without too much    reduction of other functionality.